# Transpose multiple values with associated ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to transpose multiple values in Excel by associating it with the ID in column H. Also, I would like to avoid populating blank ones. For example for second row A2:G2 should be transposed A7:A13 with associated ID in H column then 
it should continue like this.

I used this

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:G1)&TRANSPOSE(H1) but got #VALUE! this error
```

[Here is what it should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfLUA.png)

Comment: '*It didn't work.*' is not a valid error code. Add sample data together with expected results to your question.

Comment: #VALUE!
 this is what I get .Also attached screenshot for desired outcome

Comment: The #VALUE! is because the formula must be an array formula.  Press CTRL-SHIFT-Enter while curse is in field. but I don't think this will do what you want.  another approach would be to "UNPIOVT the data"  Example here: https://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel

Comment: Your results don't make sense.  There is nothing in your source data (or your formula) showing `AVOID`; and your results omit the entries from ID's 3 & 4

Comment: Avoid is representing blank fields. That is why it is yellow highlighted

Comment: You can do this with a simple unpivot operation, during the course of which you can decide what you want with the empty cells.  You use `Power Query` or `Data ► Get & Transform ► from table`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want formulas then:

First fill the second column, in B8:

```
=INDEX(H:H,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$G$5)/($A$2:$G$5<>""),ROW(1:1)))
```

Then in A8:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$G$5,MATCH(B8,$H$2:$H$5,0),COUNTIF($B$8:B8,B8))
```

Then drag/copy down.

This assumes that the data is all left justified, as in all the blank cells are to the right and not mixed in.

[image]

Comment: This is life saver !!! Thank you only bad thing I can tell is it takes forever to make the calculation

Comment: Make sure you are not using full column references inside the aggregate.  That will speed things up.

Comment: Also, please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.